# How to create a group of property groups?

Tags: python, materials, add-on, properties, panel

I need to create various kind of materials, so I made myself an add-on to make it easier. But I have like two dozens of kind of materials, declined with hundreds of colors. Until now, i made it up with one propertyGroup which contained string, integers and others properties for each type of material. Each property is used in an operator to create a material with scale, color, specular, normal map, etc.

But it becomes really too heavy, and I am trying to regroup each kind of material as a property group, with properties for each (scale, normal image, name, etc). But having two dozens of propertygroup doesn't seems more practical at all.

So I am asking, in blender is there an easier way to create different groups of properties ?

What i would like is to be able to access to a bunch of properties, like :
bpy.data.scene['Scene'].materialtypes.tissue.scale
bpy.data.scene['Scene'].materialtypes.button.color

and be able to use some :
for i in bpy.data.scene['Scene'].materialtypes :
i.scale = (20,20,20)

or something like that. Until now, i used a simple :

```
for i in ("tissue", "button", "seams") :
      scale = mytool[i + "_scale"]
```

but I have now tons of properties like tissue_scale, tissue_bool, tissue_color and blender tells me it doesn't find them anymore (error message : cannot concatenate nonetype to string)

Can someone tell me a better way to make this addon ? Thanks by advance.

Comment: I just keep trying with a collectionproperty, but blender just shuts down when I apply my  script. Don't know what I'm doing wrong...